# Upload rules don't overwrite on IC

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made a formulary with 2 diferents uploads and diferents rules (one for image and one for archive), the image upload works, but when goes to archive the rules dont overwrite (continues with the rules of the image).

I tried to load the library on construct, dont work.

The function of Image Upload:

```
    $configImagem['upload_path']   = './files/noticias/imagens';
    $configImagem['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $configImagem['file_name']     = 'Img_noticia_'.date('y-m-d_h-i-s');
    $this->load->library('upload',$configImagem);

    $check = $this->upload->do_upload('imagem');

    if($check == TRUE){ 
        return TRUE;
    } else if($check == FALSE){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('erro', '<strong>Erro:</strong>'.$this->upload->display_errors());
        return FALSE;
    }
}

public function upArquivo(){
    $configArq['upload_path']   = './files/noticias/arquivos';
    $configImagem['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|txt|doc';
    $configArq['file_name']     = 'Arq_noticia_'.date('y-m-d_h-i-s');
    $this->load->library('upload',$configArq);
    $this->upload->initialize($configArq);

    $checkArq = $this->upload->do_upload('arquivo');

    if($checkArq == TRUE){ 
        return TRUE;
    } else if($checkArq == FALSE){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('erro', '<strong>Erro:</strong>'.$this->upload->display_errors());
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$configImagem` has to be `$configArq`.

Answer (score 1):

In you archive method remove `initialize` method and keep load library:

```
$this->load->library('upload', $configArq);
```

Reloading the library should work in this case .. and check your configs.

Comment: Are you sure you fixed this `$configImagem['allowed_types']` in archive method?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 2nd parameter and set it to true to reset.

```
$this->upload->initialize($configArq, TRUE);
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::initialize